# SQL to LINQ conversion failed

Tags: c#, linq

I've an `sql` query like this:

```
select attendance.intime, attendance.outtime, attendance.date, employees.name from employees left join attendance on employees.id = attendance.employeeid where attendance.date = '12/12/2016'
```

I want to convert this to `LINQ` method syntax. I've tried this.

```
var attendances = db.Attendances.Include(a => a.Admin).Include(a => a.Employee);
var employees = db.Employees.Include(a => a.Admin);

var linq_query = attendances
                .Join(
                    employees,
                    a => a.EmployeeId,
                    e => e.Id,
                    (a, e) => new { e.Name, a.InTime, a.OutTime, a.Date                                 
                 })
                 .Where(e=> e.Date == DateTime.Parse("12/12/2016"));
```

But it's giving me 500 Internal server error. Where to change?

Comment: The 500 error could be many, many things. Do you have the `InnerException` from the debugger?

Comment: By removing `.Where()`, 500 internal error is not showing. And that also it's giving as a result of `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`..

Comment: If you know the date, why don't you use an actual DateTime object instead of parsing? Eg use `new DateTime(2016,12,12)`. Otherwise you will definitely run into parsing errors - what is the correct way to write December 13 in you *server's locale*?

Comment: Why are you trying to parse a string? The various DateTimePicker controls can return a `DateTime` value in addition to a text value. JavaScript code can also be modified to post dates in the unambiguous ISO8601 format.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
var result = from e in db.Employees
         join a1 in db.Atendances on e.Id equals a1.EmployeeId into g1
         where a1.Date == new DateTime(2016, 12, 12)
         from a in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new {
            a.intime,
            a.outtime,
            a.date,
            e.name
         };
```

Comment: `where a1.Date = new DateTime(2016, 12, 12)` giving debugging error. `a1 does not exists in the current context`